# Getting indices of a data frame that correspond to bootstrap-sampled unique values

Tags: r

I want to find the indices of a data frame that correspond to sampled *with replacement* values of my data, and I want the indices to be oversampled as well.  Because of the oversampling, `which` doesn't work.  A `foreach` loop is simple, but too slow.  Here's a dummy example:

```
  library(foreach)
  library(dplyr)
  # sample unique values of a variable, with replacement
  samp <- sample(unique(mtcars$carb), replace = TRUE)
  # using which doesn't account for oversampling
  which(mtcars$carb %in% samp) 
  # here's what I want to do, but in a slow loop
  foreach(i = samp, .combine = c) %do% {which(mtcars$carb == i)}
```

Is there a way of getting repeated indices based on repeated values, that avoids the loop?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Using `find.matches` from `Hmisc` package gives the same result in different order. But I am not sure if your appraoch is already faster.

```
set.seed(123)
data <- floor(runif(20) * 10)
smpl <- sample(data, 10, replace = T)
matches <- Hmisc::find.matches(smpl, data)$matches
matches[matches > 0] %>% unlist

[1] 6  7 13  5  7 15  5  3  6  3 18  9 11  9 11 10 18 10 14 20 14 20 12 12
```

Using your `foreach`

```
foreach(i = smpl, .combine = c) %do% {which(data == i)}

[1]  6 18  7  9 14 13  5 11 20  7  9 14 15  5 11 20  3 10 12  6 18  3 10 12
```

Comment: Nope.  `match` only returns the first match

Comment: Sorry, should have run your foreach to see what you wanted. Found a different way of doing it, but probably there is not really a better alternative avoiding the loop.